# How to generate a javascript file with nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

My site requires a JSON which I can generate during the build process.

So, what I would like to do is generate a js-file with, for example, the following content:

```
export const PREFIX = 'foo';
export const IMPORT_STUFF = {
     a: 10,
     ....
}
```

The easiest way, for me, would be something like this:

```
const TEMPLATE = `export PREFIX = '--foo--';
export const IMPORT_STUFF = `;

let output = TEMPLATE.replace('--foo--', myPefix);
output += JSON.stringify(importObj);

createJsFile(output);
```

When things get more complex I can imagine that this approach is not ideal, so I was wondering if there are better ways to do something like this?

Comment: Use any real templating engine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [ejs](https://ejs.co/) to render some basic templates. It's a templating engine usually used to render javascript inside html, but in this case you'll be rendering javascript inside a string.

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
var myPrefix = 'foo';
var importObj = {a: 10}

const TEMPLATE = `export PREFIX = '<%= Prefix %>';
export const IMPORT_STUFF = <%- JSON.stringify(ImportObj) %>`;

let output = ejs.render(TEMPLATE, {Prefix: myPrefix, ImportObj: importObj});
```

The code enclosed in `<%= %>` or `<%- %>` will be executed as javascript, using the object you provide as the second argument to `ejs.render`. 
The syntax `<%- %>` is used when you don't want to html encode the output.

If ejs is too much for you you can always go back to plain string interpolation (provided by [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```
var myPrefix = 'foo';
var importObj = {a: 10}
importObj = JSON.stringify(importObj)

var output = `export PREFIX = '${myPrefix}';
export const IMPORT_STUFF = ${importObj}`
```

However this doesn't allow you to read the template from an external file for example, so I would go for ejs which is the better option in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the native method [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to write plain JavaScript objects in a file like this :

```js
// ...

// If we wants to adds the 'module.exports = ' part before 
fs.writeFileSync( process.cwd() + '/file.js',  'module.exports = ');

// Writes the plain object to the file
fs.appendFileSync( process.cwd() + '/file.js',  util.inspect(options));
```

I have more detailed my solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077042/8027308) if anyone needs