# Update (write to) an object in a separate JS file using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm fairly new to Node, and am wracking my brains on how to achieve the following:

I have a config file that looks something like this:

```js
// various es imports

export default {
  input: {
    index: 'src/index.ts',
    Button: 'src/Button/index.ts',
    Spinner: 'src/Spinner/index.ts',
    'icons/Notification': 'src/_shared/components/icons/Notification.tsx',
    'icons/Heart': 'src/_shared/components/icons/Heart.tsx',
  },
  //.. other properties
}
```

From my node script, i need to somehow read this file and do the following:

1. Delete any entries in the `input` object that have a key starting
   with `icons/`
2. Append new entries to the `input` object.
3. Write these changes back to the original config file.

Is there a recommended way to do this in Node, i've been looking at a couple of libs, like `replace-in-file` but none seem to be suited to this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same concern, here is how I solved it :

#### 1. Gets your file content

- If it is not a `.js` file, then use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) (or `fs.readFile`) like so :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const myObjectAsString = fs.readFileSync( 
  path.join( process.cwd(), 'my-file.txt' ), // use path.join for cross-platform
  'utf-8' // Otherwise you'll get buffer instead of a plain string
);

// process myObjectAsString to get it as something you can manipulate
```

> Here I am using [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd), in case of a CLI app, it will gives you the current working directory path.

- If it is a `.js` file (eg. a JavaScript config file like `webpack.config.js` for instance), then simply use `require` native function, as you would do with regular internal file or NPM module, and you will get all `module.export` content :

```js
const path = require('path');
const myObject = require( path.join( process.cwd(), 'myFile.js') );
```

#### 2. Modify your object as you want

```js
// ...
myObject.options.foo = 'An awesome option value';
```

### 3. Then rewrite it back to the file

You can simply use [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) to achieve that :

```js
// ...
fs.writeFileSync( path.join(process.cwd(), 'my-file.txt', myObject );
```

If you want to write a plain JavaScript Object, then you can use [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) native method and you may also use [`fs.appendFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options) :

```js
// ...

// If we wants to adds the 'module.exports = ' part before 
fs.writeFileSync( process.cwd() + '/file.js',  'module.exports = ');

// Writes the plain object to the file
fs.appendFileSync( process.cwd() + '/file.js',  util.inspect(options));
```